# How is something "selected" which then triggers an event?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

What I mean by this is for example, you have two containers, one on the left, one on the right.

Content is in the left and when you "select" it, items are displayed on the right.

I could use a solution such as hiding via javascript / `display: none/inline-block;`

I thought of a radio button but I'm not sure if that is limited to a physical button, I had hoped on clicking the panel and the border is highlighted to signal that it has been selected.

Comment: Use jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` is also a solution.

Comment: So "select" is faked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly basic example.  I think this is what you are trying to accomplish.  http://jsfiddle.net/y8qko88g/1/

```
<div id="wrap">
    <input type="button" id="left" value="left" />
    <input type="button" id="right" value="right" />
</div>

$(function(){
    $("#right").hide();

    $("#left").click(function(){
        $("#left").hide();
        $("#right").show();
    });
    $("#right").click(function(){
        $("#left").show();
        $("#right").hide();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a little more advanced option done with only javascript.  http://jsfiddle.net/1dy4ogzb/

```
<form id="radioButtons">
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="left" checked="checked" />Left
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="right" />Right
</form>
<div id="left">this is left</div>
<div id="right" class="hideMe">this is right</div>

(function() {
    var trans = document.forms['radioButtons'].elements['foo'];
    var l = document.getElementById("left");
    var r = document.getElementById("right");

    for (var i=0, len=trans.length; i<len; i++) {trans[i].onchange = function() {
        if(this.value === "left"){
            l.className = "";
            r.className = "hideMe";
        } else{
            l.className = "hideMe";
            r.className = "";
        }
        };
    }
}());
```

Comment: This isn't it. Imagine a file structure, you have two windows, one on the left, one on the right. There are files on the left, which when a file is "selected", options appear on the right, which is proprietary to that selected file. I can do it with display and jQuery as Turtle mentioned, I'm not sure if there is another way the "official" way.